# Facing trouble accessing with “Service Endpoint” enabled on the Computer Vision Cognitive services

Tags: computer-vision, azure-cognitive-services

As described in the below link, facing trouble if we need to access the result with "Operation-Location" URL which is not same as the Computer Vision API endpoint.

Extract printed and handwritten text using the Computer Vision REST API and Python
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/computer-vision/quickstarts/python-hand-text

Can you please help on this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using the "Operation-Location" URL you can use the COMPUTER_VISION_ENDPOINT such as https://westus2.api.cognitive.microsoft.com.

```
text_recognition_url = endpoint + "/vision/v3.0/read/analyze"

# Set image_url to the URL of an image that you want to recognize.
image_url = "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/master/articles/cognitive-services/Computer-vision/Images/readsample.jpg"

headers = {'Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key': subscription_key}
data = {'url': image_url}
response = requests.post(
    text_recognition_url, headers=headers, json=data)
response.raise_for_status()
```